# IntelliJ: Jump between companion object and last cursor position

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, Is there any keyboard or navigational shortcut to jump between a Kotlin class's companion object and the last cursor position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl + F12` commands will show the functions in the current class including inner classes. I don't think there would be anything in particular ur looking for.

OTOH you could create anonymous bookmarks and navigate b/w them - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks

> To add a bookmark on a line `Ctrl + Shift + {Digit}`
>
> Then use Ctrl + {Bookmark digit} for navigating.

Comment: Yeah. That's nice.

Comment: @theapache64 Please feel free to accept the answer if you found it helpful !! 

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to a definition using `CTRL + B` and navigate between the previous/next cursor position using `CTRL + ALT + LEFT/RIGHT` (I am not familiar with the Mac keymap, they might look similar)

Comment: I want to navigate to companion object, not to method definition.

Comment: I am not proficient in Kotlin, so my assumption was that it was similar. My bad.